# Reason to delay security patches

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Just today my organization installed the March Windows 10 patch because of WannaCry.  We hadn't been updated since October.  Even now, we are still 3 updates behind.

They say it's because they need to check if these security patches will break our systems.  This sounds like Corporate IT power tripping to me.  Is this a legitimate concern?  Isn't the risk by not patching much greater?

Comment: "Is this a legitimate concern?" - *Yes* it is.  " Isn't the risk by not patching much greater?" - The only people who can determine that is your IT Department.

Comment: I'd like to see an example where a security patch broke something.

Comment: What does your research indicate?  Feature updates (1511,1607,1703) have created application support problems in the past.  What your IT department doesn't want to have happen, is to roll out a specific update, and then have to go to hundreds (or dozens) of computers and remove a single patch manually.  *Your request for an example of a security update breaking something is not reasonable.*

Comment: There is one specific security patch to Windows Server 2012 R2 which changes how machine group policies are pushed to machines on the domain, if you don't do something specific, those policies end up not being pushed at all.  This means your entire domain stops working if that specific machine group policy it vital for it to funciton.

Comment: It might be a good idea to hold back a patch, roll it out in waves and do tests. However mostly the patch is just hold back until somebody remembers to activate it. That is not very helpful. (Of course no IT department would say so)

Comment: I can give you a significant example: my home WiFi network is WEP-based, because of historic devices I need to support (my location means that WiFi security is not a primary concern). Earlier this year I lost WiFi connectivity from all my W10 machines, and I needed to create a new WPA-based WiFi to support them. I've never found a reference for this problem, and I took the easiest way out for my four W10 machines, but you can imagine what a change like this could mean for a network with hundreds of nodes. So your IT department's caution is well-founded.

Comment: This is such a vague question that it is likely to generate much ado about principles, tenets, dogmas, ideas, in one word noise. It does not belong on StackExchange, I voted to close it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is a philosophical question, not an IT support question.

Comment: Having been on the receiving end of a patch that basically killed half the programs on every machine in the office and meant that the IT guy had to go through manually removing the offending patch from every machine... yes, it is a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT departments are in a very difficult position when it comes to security updates and they have responsibilities that are at odds with each other.  On one hand, their entire job is to provide a stable IT platform that the business can run on.  On the other hand, part of keeping that platform stable, means keeping machines up date with security patches.

Based on your short description, it sounds like your company's IT department is either lazy or overworked.  I tend to think its probably the latter since that is a very common thing for IT departments.  They know they should be applying patches every month, but that requires testing the patches against all of the machine configurations in the enterprise to make sure they don't break any drivers, and then testing them against all of the internal, business critical applications to make sure they don't cause downtime for hundreds of employees.  That takes time, a lot of time, and if the IT department is already overworked, that could mean they find it acceptable to do all that testing every six months, instead of every month.

As for, actual apps getting broken by updates, it does happen, and as I mentioned before it is IT's job to keep the enterprise IT infrastructure stable.  Below I'll list a couple of instances where Windows Update caused widespread breakages of consumer machines.  Please note, these kinds of breakages tend to happen more in the enterprise with custom apps and infrastructure:

- [Microsoft Delivers Yet Another Broken Windows 10 Update](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/81659/microsoft-delivers-yet-another-broken-windows-10-update)
- [Microsoft, Please Stop Breaking My PC With Windows 10’s Automatic Updates](https://www.howtogeek.com/298940/microsoft-please-stop-breaking-my-pc-with-windows-10s-automatic-updates/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a legitimate concern, even though I think the delay doesn't need to be that large. Basically, Microsoft has been releasing broken Windows Updates in the past that caused problems on some computers, and they don't let the user choose only to install security updates (because some dumb Windows 10 Telemetry update is tagged "important" too ...).

I'd say a delay of one to two weeks is acceptable for Windows updates so that the IT department can test whether they don't break anything very important, because this can indeed happen. Delaying updates for half a year or even longer is definitely not acceptable.